# generate querystring with array

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, querystringparameter

For my custom paging I want to add an array of int's to the querysting (filtering)

this my code in the view:

```
            @foreach(var page in ViewBag.pagination){
                 string index = Convert.ToString(page.index);
                 if (page.skills != null) 
                 {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink(index, "index", "vacancy", new { skills= string.Join("&skills=", page.skills)}, null)</li>
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink(index, "index", "vacancy", new {page = page.index}, null)</li>
                 }
            }
```

this line

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink(index, "index", "vacancy", new { skills= string.Join("&skills=", page.skills)}, null)</li>
```

results in: ?skills=1%26skills%3D2

but how can i change the querystring into this: ?skills=1&skills=2 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink(index, "index", "vacancy")+"?"+string.Join("&", page.skills.Select(s=>"skills="+s)))</li>
```

Comment: Although this is almost certainly a working, stphn may be better served by building a route value dictionary to handle the array, IMHO.